# Getting SOS Job Scheduler 1.13 to work with AdoptOpenJDK

Tags: job-scheduler

Does anyone know how to get [SOS Job Scheduler](https://www.sos-berlin.com/en) version 1.13 working with an AdoptOpenJDK JDK 8 on Windows? The Job Scheduler itself seems to work, but the JOC tool won't run, failing to find a JVM.

The Windows Service for JOC gets stuck in the "Starting" state, and the following appears in its log file:

```
[2019-12-08 12:14:36] [info]  [ 2168] Commons Daemon procrun (1.0.15.0 64-bit) started
[2019-12-08 12:14:37] [info]  [ 2168] Running 'sos_joc' Service...
[2019-12-08 12:14:37] [error] [ 2916] Unable to find Java Runtime Environment.
```

I'm currently running SOS Job Scheduler 1.11, and was able to get that running by setting the `vm` properties in `config\factory.ini` and `config\sos.ini` to point to the `bin\server\jvm.dll` inside the AdoptOpenJDK installation. I set the same things in the 1.13 Job Scheduler configuration. But I don't see anywhere in the "Jetty" config files for JOC 1.13 to make a similar setting.

I have added the AdoptOpenJDK JRE directory to the system `%PATH%` as suggested by the SOS config files, but that had no apparent effect. I also set the system `%JAVA_HOME%` and `%JRE_HOME%` to point to AdoptOpenJDK; also no effect. I'd rather not do these things anyway, because these are global settings which would affect other applications also running on this server.

We're not running Oracle JDK/JREs because of Oracle's new Java licensing terms, where it's no longer free-as-in-beer for production use.

This is on Windows Server 2016 Datacenter on Azure.

Comment: Since the service is started by [procrun](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-daemon/procrun.html), there is probably an executable named `prunmgr.exe` or `sos_jocw.exe` in the installation directory. Run it to configure the service.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a bit late but I've gotten it to work. Your paths may be different so I'd check those before running commands. Here's how.

Install OpenJDK13U-jdk_x64_windows_openj9_13.0.2_8_openj9-0.18.0.msi from
 https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk13-binaries/releases/download/jdk-13.0.2%2B8_openj9-0.18.0/OpenJDK13U-jdk_x64_windows_openj9_13.0.2_8_openj9-0.18.0.msi

Make sure system environment variable JAVA_HOME is set to the AdoptOpenJDK path.
Mine is C:\Program Files\AdoptOpenJDK\jdk-13.0.2.8-openj9\bin and should be the default.

Also make sure system environment variable PATH includes the AdoptOpenJDK path.

- Install jobscheduler_windows-x64.1.13.2.zip from 
  https://sourceforge.net/projects/jobscheduler/files/JobScheduler.1.13/JobScheduler.1.13.2/jobscheduler_windows-x64.1.13.2.zip/download
- Install jobscheduler_windows-x64_joe.1.13.2.zip from
  https://sourceforge.net/projects/jobscheduler/files/JobScheduler.1.13/JobScheduler.1.13.2/jobscheduler_windows-x64_joe.1.13.2.zip/download
- Install joc_windows.1.13.2.zip from
  https://sourceforge.net/projects/jobscheduler/files/JobScheduler.1.13/JobScheduler.1.13.2/joc_windows.1.13.2.zip/download

Open a command prompt with administrative rights, run the following commands-

```
"C:\Program Files\sos-berlin.com\joc\service\set_java_home_for_jetty_windows_service.cmd" "C:\Program Files\AdoptOpenJDK\jdk-13.0.2.8-openj9"
cd "C:\Program Files\sos-berlin.com\joc\jetty_base"
"C:\Program Files\AdoptOpenJDK\jdk-13.0.2.8-openj9\bin\java" -jar "C:\Program Files\sos-berlin.com\joc\jetty\start.jar" --create-startd --add-to-start=jsp
```

You would still get an error like this:

```
Error scanning entry com/ibm/icu/impl/data/LocaleElements_zh__PINYIN.class from jar file:///C:/Users/Username/.m2/repository/com/ibm/icu/icu4j/2.6.1/icu4j-2.6.1.jar"
```

This is a known issue with this version of the icu4j-2.6.1.jar file.  You have to replace it.
Download the icu4j-65_1.jar file from 
https://github.com/unicode-org/icu/releases/download/release-65-1/icu4j-65_1.jar.

C:\ProgramData\sos-berlin.com\joc\jetty_base\webapps\joc.war file has to be updated with the new icu4j file.

Copy the joc.war to its own temporary folder.
Run the following command in your open command prompt:

```
cd C:\YourTempFolder
jar -xvf joc.war
```

Delete the icu4j-2.6.1.jar file in the WEB-INF\lib folder. 
Copy the icu4j-65_1.jar file into the WEB-INF\lib folder.

Run the following command in your open command prompt:

```
rm joc.war   
jar -cvf joc.war *
rename "C:\ProgramData\sos-berlin.com\joc\jetty_base\webapps\joc.war" "C:\ProgramData\sos-berlin.com\joc\jetty_base\webapps\joc.war.old"
copy joc.war C:\ProgramData\sos-berlin.com\joc\jetty_base\webapps
```

Reboot the machine.

Open Task Manager, select the Services tab, and make sure the sos_scheduler_YourMachinename_40444 service is Running.
If not, make sure the sos_joc service is stopped, and then start the sos_scheduler_YourMachinename_40444 service.
Once that is running, start the sos_joc service.

Click on the link on the desktop to Open JOC.
You should be good to go.

Comment: Sorry about the formatting.  This website strips some spacing and line feeds but everything you need should be there.  Enjoy.